# Concatenating all elements in list into a string python

Tags: python

This one should be quick but for some reason I can't think of it. So say I have a list of elements n length (the number of elements will change at some point in the future). However, let's use this one as an example:

```
['ESZ12', 'ESH13', 'ESM13', 'ESU13', 'ESZ13']
```

Now what I would like is to output this into a string that looks like this:

```
("ESZ12", "ESH13", "ESM13", "ESU13, "ESZ13")
```

The first one is indeed a list of elements and the second is just a complete string.

Thanks

Comment: 2nd one is not a string, it's a tuple. You can get it using `tuple(your_list)`.

Comment: The second one is not a string, but a tuple.

Comment: .. into a string that looks like **a tuple** ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [4]: l = ['ESZ12', 'ESH13', 'ESM13', 'ESU13', 'ESZ13']

In [5]: print('(' + ', '.join('"%s"' % el for el in l) + ')')
("ESZ12", "ESH13", "ESM13", "ESU13", "ESZ13")
```

Comment: I would simply do `str(tuple(l))`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: The output of that would use different quotes to what's specified in the question. More generally, the format would be entirely at the mercy of the Python implementation, and outside the programmer's control.

Comment: How about `print str(tuple(lis)).replace("'",'"')`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a string that looks like a tuple the easiest way is convert to a tuple:

```
>>> l = ['ESZ12', 'ESH13', 'ESM13', 'ESU13', 'ESZ13']
>>> str(tuple(l))
"('ESZ12', 'ESH13', 'ESM13', 'ESU13', 'ESZ13')"
```

Comment: @Aniket how's it wrong, just do `print str(tuple(l))`, what you're seeing is a `repr()` version , that is due to the console.

Comment: The output needed `"`(double quotation) and not single quotation.

Comment: `("ESZ12", "ESH13", "ESM13", "ESU13", "ESZ13")` is required, and the output is `"('ESZ12', 'ESH13', 'ESM13', 'ESU13', 'ESZ13')"`

Comment: @Aniket that can be easily managed by `replace()` : `str(tuple(lis)).replace("'",'"')`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary without the `replace()` it _is_ wrong output. And that's what my comment was about.

Answer (score 2):

use `join` function :

```
>>> a = ['ESZ12', 'ESH13', 'ESM13', 'ESU13', 'ESZ13']
>>> '("' + '", "'.join(a) + '")'
'("ESZ12", "ESH13", "ESM13", "ESU13", "ESZ13")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a string?

```
"".join(my_list)
```

Turn it into a tuple?

```
my_tuple = tuple(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

the expected output is a tuple. If you really meant string, then you can use:

```
strx = ''
strx.join(list)
```

Comment: Please don't name a variable after a builtin

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?:

```
    x = ['ESZ12', 'ESH13', 'ESM13', 'ESU13', 'ESZ13']
    y = str(tuple(x))
    print y
```

You get:

```
    "('ESZ12', 'ESH13', 'ESM13', 'ESU13', 'ESZ13')"
```

As a result.

Answer (score 0):

Although % formatting has been deprecated, there are cases where it is useful.  For example, the code

```
x = ['ESZ12', 'ESH13', 'ESM13', 'ESU13', 'ESZ13']
print '("%s")' % '", "'.join(x)
```

produces:

```
("ESZ12", "ESH13", "ESM13", "ESU13", "ESZ13")
```

Of course, changing the print to

```
print '("{}")'.format('", "'.join(x))
```

gives the same result, without using deprecated %.